# Controlling 20 meter RGB LED strips via APP

Tags: arduino, rgb, led

I am designing a solution where I can control around 20 meters of multicolour  LED Strips in  room via a PC/Windows or WEB application probably using Arduino.
The application should give the RGB value All the strips and they will light with the same colour. so the whole 20 meters will light with the same colour

Can you please advice me to the best way to do so using any controller in your mind, I prefer if the controller has an API for .Net apps but I am open to any suggestions.
Do you think that I can control the 20 meters LED strips with only one controller or I might need more than one?
Is there specific LED strips that must be used or any type will work fine for the purpose?

Thanks a lot for any help you would provide.

Comment: I'd say that any controller would do. You might want to go with something like an arduino, a beagle bone or raspberry pi. All would do fine. If you go with beagle bone or raspberry pi, you'll probably end up writing apps on Linux. While with arduino, you will be using the arduino APIs to write everything. Just revisit the number of pins needed to control your led strips.

Comment: What kind of LED strips are you using for this. Is it just regular PWM driven RGB LEDs or are you using NeoPixel or DotStar LEDs because those kind of LEDs need a clock signal to function properly. For driving such a thing, you can of course use an Arduino with an Ethernet or Wifi shield and have it pull data of a web-server. It is not that hard to do actually.

Comment: Thanks Mido and theAlse

My main problem at the moment is that for most of the controller they support specific length of RGD Led Strips, depending on the amount of (LED per meter) ratio. I am open to use any kind of RGB led strips, no restriction here. the only restriction I have got is that I need to work with .Net code to include the solution in my .Net project. so If you have got a specific controller in mind for example a specific Arduino equipment and the LED strip type that suits it... I would appreciate your help big time.

Answer (score 0):

Because of the length (20m) and the fact that you need to control all strips to the same colour I suggest having a look at either analog or digital RGB LED strips. They don't need to be addressable if you need to use the same colour.

Figure out what constraint you have for the installation site (e.g. indoors/outdoors/proximity to power/light intensity/etc.). 
In terms of control, you should be able to use an LED Driver or a DMX Dimmer and Controller.

In terms code, doing a search I spotted [QuickDMX](https://quickdmx.codeplex.com/) which should be able to prepare valid DMX packets for a USB DMX Controller. Regarding LED Controllers, my hunch is each manufacturer will use it's own protocol, but hopefully nothing too complicated a specification and Serial library(e.g. **System/IO/Ports/SerialPort**).